# W3 Total cache plugin breaking images on upload?

Tags: wordpress

I added the wordpress plugin for w3 total cache as i was wanting to optimise my wordpress page.
I followed the required steps, and added the content as told by the plugin into wp-config.php and .htaccess file. So everything was fine. Page loading speed did decrease. But when i was making a new blog post. and when i uploaded a photo from my local system onto the post.

The results are so:
[image]

on upload to wordpress:

[image]

So now what i did was , uninstall the plugin from the wordpress dashboard. But still no change.
And then i deleted off all the files that the plugin asked me to make.
Still no change.

What can be the reason for this to occur? Has anyone come across this issue before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with php settings for apache. We reinstalled php and php related libraries we were using and it was resolved.